Can you use the Monster's of the Multiverse Hobgoblin's Fortune from the Many feature multiple times on the same saving throw?
I noticed that the hobgoblin as it appears in MotM has a feature where it could gain a bonus to saving throws dependent on how many allies are near you (feature quoted below). The problem is that this feature does not require a reaction to activate, only that you miss an attack or fail an ability check or a saving throw. So this begs the question, if you have multiple uses of this left, you still do not hit or still fail from the first use of this feature, could you do it a second time? And if so multiple times after that if you still do not succeed?

Fortune from the Many. If you miss with an attack roll or fail an ability check or a saving throw, you can draw on your bonds of reciprocity to gain a bonus to the roll equal to the number of allies you can see within 30 feet of you (maximum bonus of +3). You can use this trait a number of times equal to your proficiency bonus, and you regain all expended uses when you finish a long rest.


No, repeated uses of Fortune from the Many will not have an added bonus.
While there's no restriction in how many times you can use the ability, the effects do not add together. You are effectively replacing the effect with the newer version each time, and wasting the ability.
To my reading, this seems to fall under this clause about Game Effects with the same name from the Dungeon Master's Guide p. 252:

Different game features can affect a target at the same time. But when two or more game features have the same name, only the effects of one of them—the most potent one apply while the durations of the effects overlap. For example, if a target is ignited by a fire elemental’s Fire Form trait, the ongoing fire damage doesn’t increase if the burning target is subjected to that trait again. Game features include spells, class features, feats, racial traits, monster abilities, and magic items. See the related rule in the “Combining Magical Effects” section of chapter 10 in the Player’s Handbook.

Note this was not present in the initial printing of the DMG, but was added as errata in later versions

Forgot about this rule. I was thinking this was a secretly game-breakingly op feature of the hobgoblin, but turns out it isn't. I do still think people don't realize how good up to a +3 to a saving throw without using a reaction is, especially since it can be used multiple times per day.
